# How to change the top margin of an element according to it's height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple code here to raise the top margin of a tooltip by it's height.

```
$("#tooltip").css({'marginTop':'-' + $("#tooltip").height});
```

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 with UI 1.9.2, and am not sure why this does not work.

tooltip is the element, margintop should be set to `-` + `tooltip.height`

example
`tooltip.height = 50px, margin-top:-50px;`

Could someone point out my error?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$("#tooltip").css("margin-top", function() { 
    return -1 * $(this).outerHeight() // <== Multiplies outerHeight() by -1 and returns the result
});
```

---

In this case, if `$.css()` receives a number, it will automatically convert to a string with 'px'.  If it receives a string, it assumes the value is complete and should be set as is.

The following would have worked as well:

```
// Passing in a number
$("#tooltip").css({'marginTop':  - $("#tooltip").outerHeight()});
$("#tooltip").css({'marginTop':  -1 * $("#tooltip").outerHeight()});
$("#tooltip").css('marginTop',  - $("#tooltip").outerHeight());
$("#tooltip").css('marginTop',  -1 * $("#tooltip").outerHeight());

// Passing in a string with units specified
$("#tooltip").css({'marginTop':  '-' + $("#tooltip").outerHeight() + 'px'});
$("#tooltip").css('marginTop',  '-' + $("#tooltip").outerHeight() + 'px');
```

While this fails as the resulting string `"-20"` is an invalid css value for marginTop:

```
$("#tooltip").css({'marginTop':  '-' + $("#tooltip").outerHeight()});
```

The string form is useful if you want to set a value using percentages or em's:

```
$("#tooltip").css({'marginTop':  "2em"});
$("#tooltip").css({'marginTop':  "10%"});
```

Comment: It sets the `margin-top` to the return value of the function. In this case itself multiplied -1, to give a negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tooltip").css("margin-top", function() { return $(this).outerHeight() });
```

Comment: This works fine except it gives a positive value for margin-top

Comment: u can do -Math.abs($(this).outerHeight()) , it will return negative number always.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tooltip").css({ marginTop: - $("#tooltip").outerHeight() + 'px' });
```

Comment: I don't know why someone voted down my answer, but here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/x2qcR/)